# Unity: Get resource path

Tags: resources, path, unity-game-engine

I work in Unity3D.

I use Resources.LoadAll(path); to load all items in the folder and subfolders. After I do this I would like to get the subfolder's name of the objects, or the complete path. Is this possible?

And don't suggest AssetDatabase, because it is an editor class, and I need it in my build.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7):

What I do is write out a "Resources/manifest.txt" file in the editor that I load in the game if I need to find files/subfolders in the Resources folder at runtime.  Creating this manifest.txt can be automated in the editor so that it's always up to date.

Then at run time instead of Resources.LoadAll, I load the manifest.txt, look for the folder/asset in there and Resources.Load it.

Comment: I already have a similar solution thought of, hoped there was a better solution. But thanks for your insights ;)

Comment: Just to confirm your suspicions, you can figure out the type of the object(s) you've loaded, but I haven't found any way to recover any part of its path.

Comment: Hi can I know how you get the files and folders. I used Directory.GetFiles, but it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

`Resources.Load()` method returns the asset at path if it can be found and if its type matches the requested generic parameter type, otherwise it returns null.

```
// Loading assets from the Resources folder using the generic Resources.Load<T>(path) method
using UnityEngine;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Start()
    {
        //Load a text file (Assets/Resources/Text/textFile01.txt)
        var textFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Text/textFile01");

        //Load text from a JSON file (Assets/Resources/Text/jsonFile01.json)
        var jsonTextFile = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("Text/jsonFile01");
        //Then use JsonUtility.FromJson<T>() to deserialize jsonTextFile into an object

        //Load a Texture (Assets/Resources/Textures/texture01.png)
        var texture = Resources.Load<Texture2D>("Textures/texture01");

        //Load a Sprite (Assets/Resources/Sprites/sprite01.png)
        var sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("Sprites/sprite01");

        //Load an AudioClip (Assets/Resources/Audio/audioClip01.mp3)
        var audioClip = Resources.Load<AudioClip>("Audio/audioClip01");
    }
}
```

For more: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html